# Jquery selector / get element by class / id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, getelementbyid

I have this JS code that I would like to apply to several images and I know that I cannot use getElementById and I have seen a lot of suggestions that suggest using either ClassByName or Selector query (?), but how do I apply that in practice? I have seen the codes but I do not know what would go where in my own code.

EDIT: Here is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvx34eag/) for clarity. I want to use the same modal code on my second image also. I have now tried all of your suggestions, but I cannot get them to work.

HTML:

```
   <a id="my-link" href="largeimage1.jpg"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg"></a>                        
     <a id="my-link" href="largeimage.jpg"><img src="thumbnail.jpg"></a>
```

JS:

```
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');
    
    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('ImgEnlarge');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption2");
    var link = document.getElementById("my-link");

link.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  modal.style.display = 'block'
  modalImg.src = link.href
})
    
    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    
    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
        modal.style.display = "none";
        }
```

Comment: IDs in HTML should be unique per page. So having `<a id="my-link">test</a><a id="my-link">test2</a>` is invalid, and your JS likely won't behave how you expect because of this. Classes, however, are reusable. So `<a class="my-link">test</a><a class="my-link">test2</a>` is valid and can be selected using `getElementsByClassName('my-link')`.

Comment: I did try changing the geElementsById to getElementsByClassName, but it does not work in practice. There must be something else in the javascript code that must be changed for this action to work properly

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function openImg(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(e.target).is("a") ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).closest("a");
    var modal = $("#modal2");
    var modalImg = $("<img>", {
      src: link.attr("href")
    }).appendTo(modal);
    modal.show();
  }

  function closeImg() {
    $("#modal2").hide().find("img").remove();
  }

  $("a").click(openImg);
  $(".close").click(closeImg);
});
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal img {
  width: 75%;
}

.modal .close {
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 90%;
  top: 3px;
  padding: .4em;
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="my-link-1" href="largeimage1.jpg">
  <img src="thumbnail1.jpg">
</a>
<a id="my-link-2" href="largeimage2.jpg">
  <img src="thumbnail2.jpg">
</a>
<div id="modal2" style="display: none;" class="modal">
  <span class="close">X</span>
</div>
```

This is a jQuery solution that sets two functions and assignes them to some basic event callbacks.

`openImg( event )` will accept the click event for a Link and reveal the Modal and append the Links target to the Modal as an Image.

`closeImg()` will hide the modal.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use same id in several elements.
Use a class to select elements.

```
<a id="my-link1" class="mylink" href="largeimage1.jpg"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg"></a>                        
<a id="my-link2" class="mylink" href="largeimage.jpg"><img src="thumbnail.jpg"></a>
```

...and change your select to this.

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("mylink");
```

and add a loop to attach each event.

Comment: How do I add a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned about jQuery but you're doing it the old school way. jQuery is a JavaScript library written to reduce DOM manipulation efforts which means instead of writing `document.getElementById("my-link")`, simply use `$("#my-link")`. With jQuery you can select and manipulate DOM elements using CSS selectors like using a period (.) to refer to a class or using a hash (#) to refer to an element's ID.

```html
  <a class="modal-trigger" href="large-image-1.jpg">
    <img src="thumbnail2.jpg" alt="Caption here" />
  </a>                        
  <a class="modal-trigger"  href="large-image-2.jpg">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt=" Second caption" />
  </a>
```

```js
  jQuery(function ($) {
    $("a.modal-trigger").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Get the image inside <a> which was clicked
      var img = $(this).find("img").eq(0);
      var modal = $("#myModal"); // Get the modal
      // Image inside modal who's `src` will be replaced.
      var modalImg = $("#ImgEnlarge")
      
      modal.css("display", "block"); // Set "display: block" on modal
      // Set the text from `alt` attribute of image as caption.
      $("#caption").text(img.attr("alt"));

      // Hide the modal when element with class (.close) is clicked.
      $(".close").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        modal.css("display", "none");
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am just a parrot repeating what I have read online, but thanks for explaining :)

Comment: Sorry, I typed it on mobile so ignore any typos.

Comment: Remember while using jQuery you just need to write `$(".my-element")` instead of `document.getElementByClassName("my-element")` and `$("#myElement")` instead of using `document.getElementById("myElement")`.